# Showing Entity Framework model in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, telerik, telerik-mvc

Currently I have this `AcceptedProposals` view, which is meant to show the details of a list of proposals, which are coming from the Entity Framework. Here's the code I have in my controller:

```
public ActionResult AcceptedProposals()
{
    var proposals = db.Proposals.Where(p => p.CollegeFundDecision == true);
    return View(proposals);
}
```

In my view I have the following line, but it's giving me this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[URGLibrary.Proposal]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'URGLibrary.Proposal'.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<Proposal>((IEnumerable<Proposal>)Model))
```

Any idea how I would be able to this this grid to show up properly? And further more, once I get this working, if I wanted to make it so that there's a dropdown of years to choose what year of proposals I'm looking at, would I be putting this grid code into a partial view?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You havent enumerated your set prior to passing it to the view. Its good practice to use .ToArray or .ToList to pre-enumerate your set in the controller so that you cant accidentally add bits to it in the view. This means your action should look like this:

```
public ActionResult AcceptedProposals()
{
    var proposals = db.Proposals.Where(p => p.CollegeFundDecision == true).ToArray();
    return View(proposals);
}
```

This relates to the ObjectQuery part of the error (a collection which hasnt yet been finalised and retrieved from the database yet).

Try this and let me know if it resolves the issue or gives you a simpler error message.